# Update the text of an element with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a `xml` look like this:

```
<san>
<sanUrunler>
<UrunStokDurum>Stokta Değil</UrunStokDurum>
</sanUrunler>
<sanUrunler>
<UrunStokDurum>Stokta Var</UrunStokDurum>
</sanUrunler>
</san>
```

I try to xslt  look like this but this not vwrking

```
<Durumu>
    <xsl:for-each select="Censan/CensanUrunler">
        <xsl:if test="UrunStokDurum='Stokta Var'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
<Durumu>
```

if `<UrunStokDurum>` inside writing 'Stokta Var' value select true otherwise false

p.s. sorry for my english

Comment: Can you show the output you expect from your XSLT? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xsl:for-each` loop does not select anything in your input XML: it looks
for `Censan/CensanUrunlur` while your input XML has `san/sanUrunlur`.

Its not really clear what you need, but in order to just print "true" or "false", you can do the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<Durumu>
  <xsl:for-each select="san/sanUrunler">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="UrunStokDurum='Stokta Var'">
          <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</Durumu>
</xsl:template>
```

The result is somewhat funny, as it looks like `<Durumu>falsetrue</Durumu>`. If you provide more information what you need as result, we could try to help.

Comment: A shortcut that can be used here: the XPath string() function will convert booleans to the string 'true' or 'false', so `<xsl:value-of select="string(UrunStokDurum='Stokta Var')">` should work without the need for the `xsl:choose`.

Comment: @bjimba The use of the `string()` function is redundant: `xsl:value-of` already does that.